# Color Emoji support In Linux Server

Tags: javascript, linux, emoji

I am using "Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS."

The Node script is running on this server, opening a headless browser to render fabricJS JSON and create an image.

While performing the above, Linux does not support color emojis, resulting in the display of monochrome emojis.

Within the JSON, I am requesting "ભારત મારો દેેેશછે ," but the output on the image shows the text with monochrome emojis. [image]

I had already put
/usr/share/fonts/NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf: Noto Color Emoji:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf: Noto Color Emoji:style=Regular

and also clear cache.

Even Update font config file and add following Lines.

```
<match>
    <test name="family"><string>sans-serif</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>serif</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>monospace</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>Apple Color Emoji</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
      <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
```